# Different webhook endpoints for different apps?

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to have different webhook endpoints for different apps in docusign? I don't seem to be able to set the app in the configurations for webhook

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try using DocuSign connect, where you can give two different webhook links for different apps. Docusign connect is also more secured.

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect

Answer (score 0):

Not through the web console - Account-level Connect configs are mostly all-or-nothing (although you can enable/disable them by sending user).

If you want one application's envelopes to write to one endpoint and another's to another, you need to set up both applications to include EventNotifications in the envelope definition.

EventNotifications are effectively a Connect configuration embedded into the envelope. They are documented in the schema of the CreateEnvelope call (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) and code examples are available here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes

Answer (score 0):

You can create two or more webhook "subscriptions" for a single account. One subscribing URL can be used for one of the apps, the other for a second app.

However, **both** URLs will receive **all** the notifications (for **both** apps).

So you need a way for both URLs' servers to only pay attention to the notifications for their own application. Easiest way is to set a metadata envelope-level field in the envelopes. This can be done either via the Envelopes:create method or set within a template.